# How to display only the higher value from a column that has multiple values from other column using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

My data is something like this

Table: customer_error

[image]

I just want to want to get the result as the error ID that appeared first for the first and not the proceeding ones.

[image]

Comment: please post your attempt as well

Comment: How should we know which occurred first?  Is it in ERROR_ID order, or some other order?  Oracle doesn't return records in any specific order unless you use an order by clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this:

here's 1 way:

```
  select distinct first_value(customer_id) over (partition by customer_id
                                      order by error_id ) customer_id,
                  first_value(error_id) over (partition by customer_id
                                      order by error_id ) error_id,
                  first_value(error_description) over (partition by customer_id
                                      order by error_id ) error_description
    from customer_error
  /
```

and a slightly different way:

```
  select customer_id, error_id, error_description
    from (
        select row_number() over (partition by customer_id
                                   order by error_id ) rnum,
               customer_id, error_id, error_description
          from customer_error
         )
   where rnum = 1
  /
```

Both use Analytics, a very useful tool for doing this sort of thing, I'd recommend reading up on it and learning it as it is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that error_number with the minimum value is the one that appeared first, we can do this with regular sql.  Our goal is to get the minimum error number per customer, and then paste the associated error description for that error onto it.

```
SELECT a.customer_id, a.error_id, b.error_description FROM
    ( SELECT customer_id, MIN(error_id) FROM customer_error
        GROUP BY customer_id) a
    LEFT JOIN customer_error b on a.error_id=b.error_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that errors are ordered by error_id and uses aggregate functions instead of analytic functions:

```
 select customer_id
      , max(error_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY error_id) error_id
      , max(error_description) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY error_id) error_description
   from customer_error
  group by customer_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a CTE and the Row_Number() function.

```
with tmp1 as
(select *, 
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by customer_id order by error_id) as RowNum
from YourTable
)

select customer_id, error_id, error_description
from tmp1
where RowNum = 1
```

Documentation on Row_Number() : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Comment: The question is tagged with oracle so providing SQL Server documentation references is misleading.